# Tornado simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, tornado

I have a TornadoAPI for keras model, is it possible to check concurrency using python multiprocessing module, I tried with below code, but it throws error

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests, json
url = 'http://localhost:8888/index/predict'
payload = { "colA":"some1", "colB":"some2",...….)
pl = json.dumps(payload)
def callAPI(x): 
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.post(url, json=json.loads(pl))
    response = r.json()
    return response
   
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    Pool(processes=15).map(callAPI, range(5))
```

Error

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Models\CallThreadsCheck.py", line 40, in callAPI
    response = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CallThreadsCheck.py", line 49, in <module>
    p.map(callAPI, range(calls))
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\HZ\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

May I know what's this error about pls.

Comment: Not sure what your loadContent does.  But the error is usually from improperly formatted Json.  I also assume from json.loads() that your payload is a Python dict to convert to json.

Comment: I tried by removing loadcontent, and assign payload = { "A":"some1","B":43....}, then pl=json.dumps(payload) and call r = requests.Session().post(url, json=json.loads(pl)), still same error

Comment: Can you debug to see what r is? Had I looked closer at your traceback, I would see that this line    response = r.json() is the last one of your program executed and it's in the JSONDecoder.

Comment: actually, it was response = r.json() and then return response, here to avoid chucky code i returned r.json

Comment: r is of type <class 'requests.models.Response'>

Comment: Ok, but r is still the problem.  r is not readily converted by the requests library json() method.  For example, I often deal with something which sends back an object with a line of json text such as r.text.  I usually convert that with json.loads(r.text) to get a dictionary to manipulate.  Therefore, I think the problem is r.

Comment: Try this then, r.content and see what you get? Also try just using curl -v to make your post and see what comes back (you can use postman as well)